"Blow away detection" to measure atom survival in a tweezer array
I am trying to understand the implementation in the following paper (PHYS. REV. X 12, 021027 (2022)) to present it as a term paper for my undergraduate course. I have a basic undergraduate background in atomic physics from doing a few courses and reading up on Dmitry Budker's textbook out of personal curiosity.
This paper mentions a "blow away resonance" method to detect the present state of atom. A beam rightly polarized at a certain resonant frequency of two of the levels (say, levels $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ of hybrid nucleus-electron spin system can cause a transition (guided by selection rules). While I don't fully understand what is going on, I tried to argue why it might be useful - If my qubit is $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, atoms at level $|1\rangle$ will be in resonance due to the incident beam and thereby absorb photon and receive a momentum kick that will blow them off of the tweezer. Therefore only atoms in state $|0\rangle$ are left in the tweezer. I can see why it would be useful to check fidelity of initialized state, but I just wanted to confirm whether the explanation is correct because I was unable to find any standard resource that discusses this technique.

@Vincent Thacker thank you for the formatting edit. I am new to the forum so could you point me toward any resource that explains how to render latex text when posting a question? I tried doing something like $\hbar$, but it didn't work.
edit: It didn't work when I was writing the comment; I can see that it renders once I post it. Thank you!

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020
